# Visual studio with xamarin Installation

Tags: c#, android

I have installed visual studio 2015 with C#/.NET(Xamarin)[3rd party] option. I am getting all the Android templates in visual studio. After created new project with Blank App(Android) template, in Main.axml file i am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR5uj.png) error. It might be path issue. Please give any solution for this. (i have installed complete xamarin also)

Thanks in Advance